# Selecting latest edition as of particular date

Tags: mysql, date, select

```
-------------------------
| ID | RID | DATE       | // TABLE A
-------------------------
| 1  | 1   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 2  | 2   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 3  | 1   | 2015-02-01 |   // 2nd edition
| 4  | 4   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 5  | 1   | 2015-05-01 |     // 3rd edition
| 6  | 6   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 7  | 6   | 2015-01-10 |     // 3rd edition
| 8  | 6   | 2015-01-12 |       // 4th edition
| 9  | 6   | 2015-01-02 |   // 2nd edition
-------------------------
```

Table A consists of records describing "file editions". So far,
I've been able to produce a SELECT statement that will pick out
the latest edition with this:

```
    SELECT `t1`.`id` AS `id`, `t1`.`rid` AS `rid`, `t1`.`date` AS `date`
    FROM `table_a` `t1`
    WHERE (`t1`.`date` = (
        SELECT MAX(`t2`.`date`)
        FROM `table_a` `t2`
        WHERE (`t2`.`rid` = `t1`.`rid`)
    ))
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
-------------------------
| ID | RID | DATE       | // TABLE B
-------------------------
| 2  | 2   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 4  | 4   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 5  | 1   | 2015-05-01 |     // 3rd edition
| 8  | 6   | 2015-01-12 |       // 4th edition
-------------------------
```

But my question is, how do tweak the SELECT statement so that I get all the latest editions as of a particular date? e.g., say I
wanted to find the latest edition as of 2015-01-11? I'd like to get a result similar to Table C:

```
-------------------------
| ID | RID | DATE       | // TABLE C
-------------------------
| 1  | 1   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 2  | 2   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 4  | 4   | 2015-01-01 | // 1st edition
| 7  | 6   | 2015-01-10 |     // 3rd edition
-------------------------
```

If there's a solution already out there, my apologies in advance but I've tried searching using these keywords/phrases: "mysql select latest edition as of date" and have found very little help so far...

Also I realize I may be overthinking this one and it could up being a really simple tweak, like perhaps modifying SELECT MAX or adding another condition to the 2nd WHERE clause.

Thanks

---

UPDATE: Thanks to Musa, I need to think about it in steps; a different method. The 1st step needs to select all dates <= 2015-01-11. 2nd step is to filter out the MAX(date) where ID = RID (ie, the latest edition). As far as merging the two SELECT statements together, I'm having some difficulty with.

Comment: but in the Table C you are choosing the newest editions

Comment: difference between Tables B and C are shown accordingly; if "as of 2015-01-11" was "as of 2015-01-12" instead, it would produce ID 8 and not ID 7…

Comment: so you want to use the older edition ?

Comment: because i'm looking for "as of --a particular date--", yes.

Comment: check the solution If it is what your are looking for?

Comment: Well 'edition' is hardly generic, so probably not a useful search term

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something as this:

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.`id` AS `id`, 
    `t1`.`rid` AS `rid`, 
    `t1`.`date` AS `date`
FROM `table_a` `t1`
WHERE 
    `t1`.`date` = (
        SELECT MAX(`t2`.`date`)
        FROM `table_a` `t2`
        WHERE (`t2`.`rid` = `t1`.`rid`)
    ) 
    and `t1`.`date` <= '2015-01-11' # I have added this line
```

You want the latest edition to be less than or equal to another date (2015-01-11 here), so I think you can get it by adding and `AND` section to your `WHERE` clause. The rest of your query is the same.

Comment: The query works, however has undesired results. It does however, clarify methodology. In this query, it filters the latest edition (MAX date), and then filters out all dates that are > 2015-01-11. Eg, it will filter out ID's 5 and 8.

Comment: @nick what do you mean by undesired result?

Comment: i only get id's 2 and 4 because they don't have later editions: the other id's have later editions but because of MAX (date), they get filtered out first and then the MAX(date) also gets filtered out because of <= 2015-01-11...

Comment: @Nick I think now I got what you mean correctly. Can you see if you get the desired result by moving the line I added to where clause of the subquey?

Comment: i get the same results

Comment: @Nick I am sorry that this is getting lengthy, but are you sure the where clause is exactly as WHERE (t2.rid = t1.rid and t2.date <= '2015-01-11' ) please note t2.date in this version, as it was t1.date previously

Comment: i've tried WHERE (t2.rid = t1.rid and t2.date <= '2015-01-11' ) [also noting t1 wouldn't work in that placement], and that did not work; it still does MAX(date) first instead of <= '2015-01-11'. the order of this is important because it will yield undesired results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96511/discussion-between-musa-and-nick).